# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. WebScraping BeatutifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am trying to save results in .csv but a receive the follow message and I have no idea how to fix that:

f.write(linha_csv)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Code Bellow:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import reader, writer

url_base = "https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/"


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_base + produto_nome).content, 
"html.parser")
produtos = soup.findAll('div', attrs =
{'class': 'andes-card andes-card--flat andes-card--default ui- 
search-result ui-search-result--core andes-card--padding-default'}
)

with open 
(r'Lista_Precos_MercadoLivre.csv','a',encoding='utf8',newline='') 
as f:
fieldnames = ['Produto','Link do Produto','Preco']

dw = csv.DictWriter(f,delimiter=';',fieldnames=fieldnames)
dw.writeheader()

i = 1
while True:
for tag in soup:
      
titulo = soup.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'ui-search- 
item__title'})
    
print(i, tag.text)
print(i,'Título do Produto:', titulo.text)
print(i,'Link do Produto:', link['href'])

next_link = soup.select_one( "a.andes-pagination__link:-soup- 
contains(Seguinte)"
)
if not next_link: break 
linha_csv = titulo.text + ';' + link['href'] + ';' + "R$" + 
real.text  + "," + centavos.text + '\n'

f.write(linha_csv)
```

Comment: please reformat your code with proper python spacing. this is unreadable. please see PEP-8 for your reference

Comment: Also make sure you have a [mcve], the full error it produces (incl. backtrace) and that you search for the error message online. The message is actually pretty clear, so it's unclear what else you need. In any case, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Cause indentation in your question is not set correct, it may caused by that fact. Moving the writing part into your `for-loop` should fix the issue:

```
for tag in soup.select('li.ui-search-layout__item'):

    linha_csv = tag.h2.text + ';' + tag.a['href'] + ';' + tag.select_one('.price-tag-amount').text + '\n'
    f.write(linha_csv)
```

##### Example

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/"
query = "vinho"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_base + query).content, "html.parser")

with open (r'Lista_Precos_MercadoLivre.csv','a',encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Produto','Link do Produto','Preco']
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f,delimiter=';',fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dw.writeheader()

    while True:
        for tag in soup.select('li.ui-search-layout__item'):

            linha_csv = tag.h2.text + ';' + tag.a['href'] + ';' + tag.select_one('.price-tag-amount').text + '\n'
            f.write(linha_csv)

        next_link = soup.select_one( "a.andes-pagination__link:-soup-contains(Seguinte)")

        if not next_link: 
            break 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(next_link["href"]).content, "html.parser")
```